# Summon Sideways FallingSand

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In the map I'm making there is a block (Jungle Stairs) that I changed to look like a 3D player. I want to have the player skim across the ground moving 'backwards'. I am wondering if you can summon FallingSand and have it move sideways. How might I summon this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, **you can't summon sideways falling sand**, but you can create an illusion of movement by rapidly summoning and destroying a falling sand block with a slight change in horizontal direction. Just set up a clock to a line of command blocks and it should do the trick.

Comment: Could you possibly use the motion tag?

Comment: You can, but gravity will kick in again.

Comment: @KingDarren7203 Happy to help!

Comment: rather than destroying and re-summoning it, I would recommend teleporting it, so you don't have to worry about reapplying scoreboard properties and such.

Answer (score 0):

you could also have made a track where there is a mob moving along a path which is summoning falling sand all the time. this is how i would do it and i would find it easier like this

Answer (score -2):

As ***@The_Basset_Hound*** said, you ***can't*** summon sand falling to ***other*** **directions**, but When you summon sand, it disappears in like 2 ticks (0.10 seconds), so if you set up a redstone block clock, you can just rapidly summon a FallingSand, and when you want to make it move, just change the coordinates (Example, if you want to make it go up: [**X Y Z**] **0 0 0**, **0 0.2 0**, **0 0.4 0**, **0 0.6 0**, **0 0.8 0**, **0 1 0**.)